# React removes key from my div and then throws error because of that

Tags: reactjs, components, key, warnings

I have a react func component that is simly returns this:

```
<div name={id} key={id}>{id}</div>
```

Problem I have is that when I use this component like so:

```
{Object.keys(data).map(key => (
    <MyComponent id={key} data={data[key]} />
))}
```

I get error `Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.` and when I look at generated html it has no key.

```
<div name="7987">7987</div>
<div name="21727">21727</div>
<div name="157119">157119</div>
<div name="232881">232881</div>
```

So the question is why is key removed and warning as error is generated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the react compiler wants the key prop in

```
<MyComponent id={key} data={data[key]} />
```

rather than

```
<div name={id} key={id}>{id}</div>
```

one way to avoid this is

```
<MyComponent id={key} data={data[key]} key={key} />
```

or to make sure there are no duplicate keys

```
{Object.keys(data).map((key, index) => (
<MyComponent id={key} data={data[key]} key={index} />
))}
```

Answer (score 0):

keys are not rendered in actual dom. The reason you're getting that error is that you didn't pass the key to MyComponent
So it should be something like this.

```
{Object.keys(data).map(key => (
    <MyComponent key={key} id={key} data={data[key]} />
))}
```

Make sure keys are not duplicated.

You can also pass index like this to avoid any duplicate.

```
{Object.keys(data).map((key, index)=> (
    <MyComponent key={index} id={key} data={data[key]} />
))}
```